# how to include cutil.h in linux

Tags: linux, cuda

I don't know how to include cutil.h in linux, i know where it is, but I don't know how to include it. Ideas please.

Comment: It seems that there is no cutil.h avaiable at the CUDA 5. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284961/cuda-5-0-replacement-for-cutil-h

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <cutil.h>
```

find out where cutil.h is:

```
sudo updatedb; locate cutil.h

nvcc -I /usr/local/cuda/include ...
```

for you

```
nvcc -I ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing/C/common/inc test.cu -o test
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your executable script has the following:

```
-I/usr/local/cuda/include \
-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 \
-I/$HOME/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc/ \
-L/$HOME/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib -lcutil_x86_64 \
```

Obviously the assumption is that the SDK is in your home directory.

Answer (score -6):

```
#include <cutil.h>
```