# CUDA cutil.h where is it?

Tags: cuda

Does anyone know which and where is the SDK/toolkits that contents cutil.h? I tried CUDA toolkits3.2 and toolkits5.0(I know this version it is not supported already for cutil.h)

Also I notice some mentioned about it in [how to include cutil.h in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765181/how-to-include-cutil-h-in-linux)

but which & where installer that generate "NVIDIA_GPU_Computing/C/common/inc"? My toolkit dont generate such files.

is CUDA3.0 only contain these cutil.h?

Comment: For linux, the CUDA SDK (not toolkit) installer versions 3.2 to 4.1 inclusive (at least) should install the .../C/common/inc/cutil.h file. It was eliminated in the CUDA 5.0 release and is not in the installer there as you have discovered.

Comment: You **should have** `cutil.h` after SDK installation just in the folder suggested by @RobertCrovella. After starting the `make` process of SDK, in early stages `libcutil.a` or `libcutil.dll` **will be generated**.

Comment: Robert or ahmad, please post as an answer. FWIW, we had good reasons to finally eliminate CUTIL from CUDA 5.0, so I highly recommend you do without it unless you are just trying to compile old versions of CUDA SDK samples...

Comment: Take a look at these threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474191/cuda5-examples-has-anyone-translated-some-cutil-definitions-to-cuda5  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982308/cuda-5-0-checkcudaerrors-fails-to-find-correct-check-method-if-class-has-a-c

Answer (score 2):

For linux, the CUDA SDK (not toolkit) installer versions 3.2 to 4.1 inclusive (at least) should install the .../C/common/inc/cutil.h file. It was eliminated in the CUDA 5.0 release and is not in the installer there as you have discovered.