# CUDA 5.0: Replacement for cutil.h?

Tags: linux, cuda

I want to compile an old project (based on CUDA 2.3) with the new CUDA 5.0
Unfortunately it makes use of the old cutil.h header, which is not available in CUDA 5.0 anymore.

Is there a replacement for this header?

Especially the image im- and export functions (PPM, PGM) are missing, e.g. cutSavePGMf()...

Comment: Why wouldn't you install the old `GPU Computing SDK` (e.g. 4.2) in different directory? I am not sure of v2.3 but It should be possible to compile SDK v4.2 with CUDA 5.0 to have `libcutil`.

Comment: Thank for this advice! I had to modify the projects source code in order to be compatible with SDK v4.2, and I wasn't able to compile the whole SDK with CUDA v5.0, but libcutil has been successfully created!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a replacement in the new SDK Examples.
It has been covered in a previous question:
[CUDA5 Examples: Has anyone translated some cutil definitions to CUDA5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474191/cuda5-examples-has-anyone-translated-some-cutil-definitions-to-cuda5)